# In ExtJS, how do you change the background color of an actioncolumn?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I have an ExtJS web application that uses an Ext.grid.ColumnModel.  For one of the columns, I need to set the background color based

```
var result = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel(
            [
                {
                    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                    header: 'Delete',
                    align: 'center',
                    width: 50,
                    border: false,
                    items: [{
                        getClass: function (v, meta, record) {
                            if ((record.get('materialType') == '95'){

                                this.items[0].tooltip = "Delete all three";
                                this.items[0].tdCls = 'background-color: #F1F1F1;';

                            }
                            else {
                                this.items[0].tooltip = "Delete just one";
                                this.items[0].tdCls = 'background-color: #FFFFFF;';
                            }


                        }

               }
```

Setting the tooltip works fine; no luck with setting the background color.  Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to use the meta param in that getClass function

`meta.attr = 'background-color: #F1F1F1;'`

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action

Answer (score 0):

the `tdCls` attribute is designed to be the name of a css class, not some css instruction. For example :

```
this.items[0].tdCls = 'myclass'
```

and in your css :

```
.myClass { background-color: #FFFFFF;}
```

If you don't want to use a class you can use the `style` attribute instead.

See http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer for more information.